# How to confirm cleverTap event push

Tags: web, clevertap

I am using this below code inside my app, but I am not sure if the events are being pushed to my dashboard and I am not even seeing any error, how to debug clever tap events

```
     var clevertap = {event:[], profile:[], account:[], onUserLogin:[], notifications:[], privacy:[]};
 // replace with the CLEVERTAP_ACCOUNT_ID with the actual ACCOUNT ID value from your Dashboard -> Settings page
clevertap.account.push({"id": "CLEVERTAP_ACCOUNT_ID"});
clevertap.privacy.push({optOut: false}); //set the flag to true, if the user of the device opts out of sharing their data
clevertap.privacy.push({useIP: false}); //set the flag to true, if the user agrees to share their IP data
 (function () {
         var wzrk = document.createElement('script');
         wzrk.type = 'text/javascript';
         wzrk.async = true;
         wzrk.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://d2r1yp2w7bby2u.cloudfront.net' : 'http://static.clevertap.com') + '/js/a.js';
         var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         s.parentNode.insertBefore(wzrk, s);
  })();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it is a bit late, but here is my answer :

When I integrated clevertap SDK, I used to point the app to the test clevertap account and test and validate the events there. The only challenge is that you have to find your profile on the dashboard. That should be easy once you know the clevertap ID OR the profile identity(if you are setting one)by looking at the debug console using ADB(for android)

Sending events is one thing, but the actual use of that data will be by the people who analyse in on the clevertap dashboard. Therefore, this method will help you understand

1. How people will see that event/data on the dashboard.
2. If profiles have been merged incorrectly (in case of multiple users)
3. If there are any issues with receiving events on the clevertap side
4. If the event names and parameters re being received on the dashboard and are correct.

More importantly, another team member (even one who is not a developer) can help you validate events(Step 4) without him having to setup anything on his/her laptop and installing a debug build. He can just look it up on the clevertap dashboard by firing events from an app that points to the clevertap TEST account!

Apart from this, I recommend using test account for testing events. This is because it helps you keep test data separate from production data and you can completely clear TEST account from the dashboard in case the data becomes too much of a mess.

Answer (score 1):

In cleverTap if the events are pushed successfully then you will get it notified  in the clevertap dashboard. **Segments** -> Find People -> **By Identity**(enter the identity) -> In the profile under **Activity** you can see all the events that are tracked in cleveTap dashboard,so in this we can confirm.